# Javascript, make ajax call after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a working javascript block that basically takes user input, and upon each keystroke makes an Ajax POST call.

This works perfectly but I'd like to change it to only fire the ajax 3 seconds after the user starts typing, as opposed to every keystroke. Ideally I'd like to fire it after 3 seconds and if they start typing again it would start over, but the initial delay is most important.

I tried to do a set interval around it but it's didn't make the ajax call, so I'm wondering if there's  different approach I need to take.

how can I make this ajax only call 3 seconds after typing in the input starts?

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function() {

  let _this = $(this);
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;

  if (_this.val() === '') {

    return;

  } else if ($('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector).length) {

    //html stuff

  } else {

    const searchResult = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
      data: {
        search_result:searchResult
      },
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      type: "POST", 
      success: function (response) {

        $("#returnedProducts").empty();
        var result = response.hits.hits;

        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $("#returnedProducts").append($("<option/>",
            {
              //option stuff
            }
          ));
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a persistent variable that holds a `setTimeout`. On input, clear the current timeout (if there is one), and set another timeout to trigger in 3 seconds (unless another input event occurs). You may also consider putting the ajax call (at least) into its own function, for the sake of less indentation hell:

```js
let timeout;
$('input').on('input', () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  console.log('timeout set');
  timeout = setTimeout(() => console.log('action running'), 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

```
let timeout;
$('#productInput').on('input', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  let _this = $(this);
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;
  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ($('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector).length) {
    //html stuff
  } else {
    const searchResult = $(this).val();
    timeout = setTimeout(ajaxCall, 3000, searchResult);
  }
});

function ajaxCall(search_result) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/account/autocomplete',
    data: { search_result },
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    type: "POST",
    success: successHandler
  });
}
function successHandler(response) {
  $("#returnedProducts").empty();
  var result = response.hits.hits;
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    $("#returnedProducts").append($("<option/>", {
      //option stuff
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like now with multiple functions I get that searchResult is not defined?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't define it in one of your functions.

Comment: So how would I loop the timeout without creating the 2 new functions? Then I'll walk it back from there

Comment: I followed your answer for the additional functions so I don't know why it wouldn't be defined but it works with  my original code. So would I just put the duration after the ajax portion of my answer?

Comment: Without seeing the code you're trying to use, it's difficult to impossible to be able to identify what the problem might be

Comment: I actually got it, I was just asking about wrapping the timeout around my existing code above, without using multiple functions. Though I did actually put the success call in an external function. Thanks!